# Do I need the preprocessor definition (DefineConstants) NET461 in a normal configuration?

Tags: c#, .net, preprocessor-directive

I am working on an inherited application that has a lot of functionality that was added very quickly as the programmers (it would seem) were learning the technologies used as they coded. The project is targeted at .NET 4.6.1 but includes some config files and other concepts from .NET Core. I am attempting to rationalise this and move it all to .NET Core following the [MS advised steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/)

Whilst moving from 4.6.1 to 4.7.2 I have come across the following preprocessor definitions in the csproj files.

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;NET461</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG;NET461</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Is specifying the target in the configuration necessary?

I have already searched and found it is normally used for multi targeting that make no sense in this application (and seems like a minefield anyway)

I don't want to change them to the new framework as I will port onwards to .NET Core. Also nothing in this project requires x64 targeting.

Comment: If you don't want to use the preprocessor definitions, don't use them. Just like you don't have to use `DEBUG`; it's there if you need it.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for that. I am looking for input on what reasons they might have been put there.

Comment: You should [edit] your question then, since it currently asks "Is specifying the target in the configuration necessary?" But you've already identified the reason: "...it is normally used for multi targeting...".

Comment: Nope. I said it is "normally" used for multi targeting which is not the case here. I await with patience and anticipation any helpful feedback.